# Parse string in HH.mm format to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, time

I'm using **.NET framework v 3.5** and i need to parse a string representing a timespan into `TimeSpan` object.

The problem is that **dot** separator is used instead of colon... For example `13.00`, or `22.30`

So I'm wondering if I have to replace `.` with `:` or there is a more clean way to obtain this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Parse out the `DateTime` and use its `TimeOfDay` property which is a `TimeSpan` structure:

```
string s = "17.34";
var ts = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 10):

**Updated answer:**

Unfortunately .NET 3 does not allow custom `TimeSpan` formats to be used, so you are left with doing something manually. I 'd just do the replace as you suggest.

**Original answer (applies to .NET 4+ only):**

Use [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784501.aspx), specifying a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx):

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("11.35", "mm'.'ss", null);
```

Comment: No `ParseExact` in `3.5` :( ! !

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: Oops... looking into alternatives.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to escape the `.` using `\.`?

Comment: @Oded: It's the same really. Picked this form at random.

Answer (score 4):

```
string YourString = "01.35";

var hours = Int32.Parse(YourString.Split('.')[0]);
var minutes = Int32.Parse(YourString.Split('.')[1]);

var ts = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
```

Comment: I like this answer the best!

Answer (score 2):

For **.Net 3.5** you may use DateTime.ParseExact and use [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property

```
string timestring = "12.30";
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                  timestring, 
                                  "HH.mm", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                  ).TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: This solution rocks! I found it on my own but it's so simple, now you get all the usual DateTime formatting options that we know and love and can use them for TimeSpan the way we expected the first time. - Note this obviously wont work for Timespans greater than 24 hours... but most of the time I have been using TimeSpan when integrating with external systems that track dates and times separately, so we never go past 23:59:59 :)

Answer (score 2):

If the TimeSpan format is Twelve Hour time format like this "9:00 AM", then use TimeSpan.ParseExact method with format string "h:mm tt", like this

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact("9:00 AM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try This(It worked for me) :

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text).Add(DateTime.ParseExact(ddlStartTime.SelectedValue, "HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay);
```

startdate will be a string like 28/02/2018 and ddlstarttime is in HH format like 13.00