# TimeSpan to string in format "hh.mm"

Tags: c#, timespan

How can I create a string in the format "hh.mm" from a given `TimeSpan` object?

The opposite of what is wanted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12493381/463828). I've got a valid `TimeSpan` object and want to parse it into a string of the given format. Two digits for he hours, a dot and two digits for the minutes.

I tried using it with the format string "hh.mm" like I would've done it with an `DateTime` object. This did not work.

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120).ToString("hh.mm")
```

This throws a System.FormatException.

Comment: What's wrong with ToString or String.Format? Have you tried something? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Read up on how to use [Custom TimeSpan Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and see if that helps.

Comment: `ts.ToString(@"hh\.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` this should do it

Comment: @Habib this gives me an error "unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: I found a solution: `ToString("mm'.'hh")`.

Comment: @PhilippM please edit your question with the actual problem and the code to reproduce it.

Comment: @PhilippM, try the code `ts.ToString(@"hh\.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` this is not going to throw the exception, if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher