# What is a simple way to convert h:m:s and m:s strings to TimeSpan object?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to convert a timestamp string to a `TimeSpan` object.
However, `TimeSpan.Parse()` doesn't work as I expect. I'll explain why.

There are two types of timestamps I'd like to convert.

1. minutes:seconds
   e.g. `30:53`, `1:23`, `0:05`
2. hours:minutes:seconds
   e.g. `1:30:53`, `2:1:23`, `0:0:3`

The issue is, type 1 is interpreted as an hours:minutes format in `TimeSpan.Parse()` method.

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.Parse("12:43"));
// the result I expect -> 0:12:43
// the actual result -> 12:43:00
```

I googled the issue and found this SO post.
[Parse string in HH.mm format to TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493381/parse-string-in-hh-mm-format-to-timespan)

This uses `DateTime.ParseExact()` to parse a string in a certain format. However, the issue is I need to use different formats for type 1 and 2.

```
// ok
var ts1 = DateTime.ParseExact("7:33", "m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
// throws an exception
var ts2 = DateTime.ParseExact("1:7:33", "m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
// throws an exception
var ts3 = DateTime.ParseExact("7:33", "h:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
// ok
var ts4 = DateTime.ParseExact("1:7:33", "h:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

I also checked MSDN but it wasn't helpful.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx

So the solutions I came up with were as follows.

A. `DateTime.ParseExact` with if

```
string s = "12:43";
TimeSpan ts;
if (s.Count(c => c == ':') == 1)
    ts = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
else
    ts = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "h:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

B. `TimeSpan.Parse` with if

```
string s = "12:43";
if (s.Count(c => c == ':') == 1)
    s = "0:" + s;
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse(s);
```

But both of them are lengthy and not "cool." it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel. I don't want them, any takers?

So what is a simple way to convert h:m:s and m:s strings to TimeSpan object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify *several* formats in the [TimeSpan.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988456(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
  string source = "17:29";

  TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(source, 
    new string[] { @"h\:m\:s", @"m\:s" }, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In the code above we try `h:m:s` format first, and then `m:s` if the first format fails.

Test:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] { 
     // minutes:seconds
    "30:53", "1:23", "0:05", 
     // hours:minutes:seconds 
    "1:30:53", "2:1:23", "0:0:3" };

  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => TimeSpan.ParseExact(
       test, 
       new string[] { @"h\:m\:s", @"m\:s" },
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
00:30:53
00:01:23
00:00:05
01:30:53
02:01:23
00:00:03
```

Comment: This is a great response. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: what would be the c# timespan parseexact format for 1.872s.  i tried  @"s\.fff" but it didn't work?

Comment: @dcarl661: It seems, that `@"s\.fff"` works properly, providing that you have text in the expected format, please, fiddle yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3CWGVz